# How to send down td on table make it break down

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to break last td down, but not with tr

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
     <td>THis I need Down row</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

So what I need is last td of every row to go down and fill all part. I repeat I don't want it to go like   I need on same row that are other tds

Comment: You'd have to change the structure of the DOM for the table, you'll need javascript to do that. Grab the last TD of each row, remove that element, then create a new TR with a single TD (colspan=3) sett the inner html to that of the TD you removed and insert it after that TR.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a minute to remember how to do this without jquery, but here's a vanilla javascript solution.

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
console.log(rows.length);

for (const row of rows) {

    var cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
  if (cells.length == 4){

    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.setAttribute('colspan', 3);
    td.innerHTML = cells[3].innerHTML;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    row.after(tr);
    cells[3].remove();
    
  
  }

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
     <td>THis I need Down row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Acme</td>
    <td>Bobby Brown</td>
    <td>USA</td>
     <td>Moving another row</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```